# Plant box in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am looking for a box in simulink that is "plant".

I cannot seem to find it in the search option of simulink.

Like the one in the next pic:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a subsystem that the person who created the model made, it's not a standard Simulink block. You need to look inside the subsystem to see how it's constructed. See [Create a Subsystem](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/creating-subsystems.html) in the documentation for more details.

Comment: You should really get yourself familiar with the basics of Simulink, for example by watching the getting started videos at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/videos.html or going through the tutorials at https://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/slregister.html.